# El fragmento se superpone en el anterior y se ven los dos al mismo tiempo

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Estuve intentando enviar datos de un fragmento a otro, lo logré, pero el dilema es que al presionar el boton "Siguiente" me sale un Fragmento encima del otro, el proyecto lo cree con un "Basic Activity" según lo quehe leido tiene algo que ver.

**FirstFragment:**

```
    view.findViewById(R.id.btnSiguiente).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String inmueble = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String inmueble2 = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("nombre", inmueble + ": " + inmueble2);

            Fragment f = new SecondFragment();
            f.setArguments(extras);
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, f);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

            //NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this)
            //     .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);
        }
    });
}
```

content_main:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas realizando la transacciòn de fragmentos en `nav_host_fragment`:

```
 ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, f);
```

pero este este es un Fragment!, lo cual es incorrecto ya que este no se podrá cambiar porque no fue agregado dinámicamente.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
```

si defines un fragment en el layout no podràs cambiar su contenido, lo que debes realizar es usar un `FrameLayout` en lugar de un Fragment y aquí si podrás realizar la transacciòn.

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Recuerda:

> Hay algo muy importante que dese saber acerca de los Fragments y es
> que **solo se pueden reemplazar aquellos Fragments que se han agregado
> dinamicamente usando código en un contenedor mediante
> FragmentTransaction.**